# Pass parameters in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am writing a module in `Verilog` that uses parameters. Later I will need to implement it several times in my project using different parameters, so instead of crating several modules I want to pass the parameters as if they were inputs, although they are specified in the compilation.

I think this can be done in `VHDL`, so I guess it can be done in `Verilog` too although I cannot find anything.

Comment: Your question is aside from using `defparam` in verilog ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to Verilog modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555273/passing-parameters-to-verilog-modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module `parameters` can be overridden in these 2 ways:

1. Using `defparam` statement:

   ```
   module Stack;

   parameter param1 =  1;
   parameter param2 = 12;

   endmodule

   module Test;

   defparam s1.param1 =  6;
   defparam s1.param2 = 32;

   Stack s1();

   endmodule
   ```
2. Passing parameters during instantiating: in this method, parameters must be overridden in the order they were defined so code below, is the same as above.

   ```
   module Stack;

   parameter param1 =  1;
   parameter param2 = 12;

   endmodule

   module Test;

   Stack #(6, 32) s1();

   endmodule
   ```

   - In Verilog 2001, there is a new feature which makes it more readable (note that above codes all work in Verilog 2001).

     ```
     module Stack;

     parameter param1 =  1;
     parameter param2 = 12;

     endmodule

     module Test;

     Stack #(.param1(6), .param2(32)) s1();

     endmodule
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```
`module top #(
parameter N, // Number of instance
parameter [(N*32-1):0] A, // First Parameter
parameter [(N*2-1):0] B   // second parameter
);
generate
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) begin: instance
  s #(.A(A[(i*32-1):0]),
      .B(B[(i*2-1):0])
     ) s_i;
end
endgenerate`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly assign parameter during the input and output assignment. for example: " parameter i0=0,i1=1;  " and call these values in code such as:" a[0]=N[i0];" =>the 0th bit of input N; will be stored in 0th bit of reg a; "a[1]=N[i1];"=> the 1th bit of input N; will be stored in 1th bit of reg a; if your N is 4'b1011, then the value of " a=0011 ". You may have to initialize a to 0.